# Player not moving to all waypoints.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Enemy character not moving to the 3rd waypoint. After moving to waypoint 2 it just stops and the idle animation plays. The character has a NavMeshAgent on it and it looks like the destination reached event is not being triggered when he gets to the waypoint. If anyone has had a situation like this before I would appreciate any information possible. I have been trying to figure out whats wrong for a few hours now and am starting to think it might not be any of the scripts.

here is the waypoint controller

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI; 

public class WaypointController : MonoBehaviour {

    Waypoints[] waypoints;
    public Transform target; 
    //NavMeshPath path; 
    int currentWaypointIndex = -1;
    //private NavMeshAgent agent;
    //EnemyCharacter enemy; 

    public event System.Action<Waypoints> OnWaypointChanged;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {

        waypoints = GetWaypoints();

    }

    public void SetNextWaypoint() {

        if (currentWaypointIndex != waypoints.Length)
            currentWaypointIndex++;

        if (currentWaypointIndex == waypoints.Length)
            currentWaypointIndex = 0;

        if (OnWaypointChanged != null)
            OnWaypointChanged(waypoints[currentWaypointIndex]);
        //Debug.Log("OnWaypointChanged == null: " + (OnWaypointChanged == null));
        //Debug.Log("OnWaypointChanged != null: " + (OnWaypointChanged != null));

    }
    Waypoints[] GetWaypoints()
    {
        return GetComponentsInChildren<Waypoints>();

    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;

        Vector3 previousWaypoint = Vector3.zero;
        foreach (var waypoint in GetWaypoints())
        { 
            Vector3 waypointPosition = waypoint.transform.position; 
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(waypointPosition, .2f);
            if (previousWaypoint != Vector3.zero)
                Gizmos.DrawLine(previousWaypoint, waypointPosition);
            previousWaypoint = waypointPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the EnemyPatrolPoints script

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AI_PathFinder))]
public class EnemyPatrolPoints : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    WaypointController waypointController;

    [SerializeField]
    float waitTimeMin;

    [SerializeField]
    float waitTimeMax;

    AI_PathFinder pathfinder;

    private void Start()
    {
        waypointController.SetNextWaypoint(); 
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        pathfinder = GetComponent<AI_PathFinder>();
        pathfinder.OnDestinationReached += Pathfinder_OnDestinationReached;
        waypointController.OnWaypointChanged += WaypointController_OnWaypointChanged;
    }
    private void WaypointController_OnWaypointChanged(Waypoints waypoint)
    {
        pathfinder.SetTarget(waypoint.transform.position);
        print("waypoint changed"); 
    }
    private void Pathfinder_OnDestinationReached()
    {
        SealForce_GameManager.Instance.Timer.Add(waypointController.SetNextWaypoint, Random.Range(waitTimeMin, waitTimeMax));
        print("destination reached"); 
    }   
}
```

Here is the AI Pathfinder script`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class AI_PathFinder : MonoBehaviour
{

    [HideInInspector]
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public EnemyPatrolPoints enemyPatrolPoints;

    [SerializeField] float distanceRemainingThreshold;

    bool m_destinationReached;
    bool destinationReached
    {
        get
        { return m_destinationReached; }

        set
        {
            m_destinationReached = value;

            if (m_destinationReached)
            {
                if (OnDestinationReached != null)
                    OnDestinationReached();
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.Action OnDestinationReached;

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        //enemyPatrolPoints = GetComponent<EnemyPatrolPoints>();
    }
    public void SetTarget(Vector3 target)
    {
        agent.SetDestination(target);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (destinationReached)
            return;

        if (agent.remainingDistance < distanceRemainingThreshold)
            destinationReached = true;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines

```
if (agent.remainingDistance < distanceRemainingThreshold)
    destinationReached = true;
```

are never reached as long as `destinationReached` is `true` because of

```
if (destinationReached)
    return;
```

You are setting it to `true` after the first waypoint is reached and then never reset it to `false` so your `Update` is always skipped in the future.

You should add it e.g. to

```
public void SetTarget(Vector3 target)
{
    agent.SetDestination(target);
    destinationReached = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It totally makes sense to why the destination reached was not triggering the second time around.